# Reading a file returns 'invalid token' errors

Tags: python

My program tries to read a file and process its contents.
The file to be processed contains

```
core-001
core-001
core-002
core-003
core-003
...
core-nnn
```

To process it, I wanted to read out every line, stuff them in a list, remove the duplicates and then put them out again in some other file.
The code for these first three things I used is as follows:

```
content = []
with open(file,'r') as openFile:
        content = [line.strip('\n') for line in openFile]
content = list(set(content))
```

([Why I use list and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists))
As far as I see, this should not have any problems, however two errors are returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file", line 1, in <module>
    core-004
NameError: name 'core' is not defined
```

and

```
File "/path/to/file", line 21
    core-009
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

What causes these errors and, more importantly, how to avoid them?

**EDIT** As also readable in the comments, but repeated here:
It was not an error in the code, it was just me not coding well enough. The errors were given by `python` trying to execute the input file as I seemed to have forgotten to give it the executable and only the parameters. After doing so it works perfectly.
I thank you for your time and your kind comments.

Comment: looks like you somehow try to eval the data file??

Comment: As noted above, Python is trying to eval the literal strings "core" and "core-009". Does the string "core" occur at all in your script?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your code ...

Comment: How can 2 errors be returned?

Comment: How are you running your code? It looks like you might be running the data file, instead of running your program file.

Comment: @TomDalton Great find.. But I'm hoping that the OP is not doing so

Comment: @PeterWood I ran it on multiple files, one by one.
@The rest: Eheh, eheh, oops. Thought I was doing `python exec param`, but apparently I forgot the 'exec' part...
I thank you for your time, I certainly would not have thought of that one -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a bit late, and I do not have any usable memory of it or the code available, so I answer this question based on the comments of [MightyPork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180189/mightypork), [Tom Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372812/tom-dalton) and myself.

Apparently the problem was that I did not run the program.
Instead of running

```
python <name>.py param1 param2 ...
```

I ran

```
python param1 param2 ...
```

which failed as my `param1` seems to have been a file containing the topmost text in the question.

I however am unaware of how I got two different error messages: I might have have been giving different files as `param1` or something alike.

Therefore it was not an error in the code, as the other answers (and my question) suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do that is

```
import sys
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
print ''.join(sorted(set(lines)))
```

Here the program takes input from the system and prints it out. You can use this as

```
python run.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Exactly why is this better?

Comment: @TheJustist You can write my code as a single command line utility

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I suggest. You should use a set, which is a built-in data type that stores only unique values. This means that there won't be any repeats just as you would like. Try this:

1. Read the lines of your file.
2. Add lines to set.
3. Convert set to list.

   ```
   content = open('file.txt').readlines() # read file's lines
   content = [item.strip('\n') for item in content] # remove newlines

   content_set = set(content) # to set to remove repeats
   content_list = list(content_set) # back to list
   ```

**EDIT** Your code actually seems to work. Perhaps, the error lies in your use of the file built-in function as a variable. Could you provide the code before and after this segment? It seems that your file is being evaluated.

Comment: You are aware my code does the exact same thing, only shorter?
And to your edit: The only place I used the file is under the `with ... as ...:`.
And at last, the answer is already found, see the comments below the question.

Comment: Yes, I added an edit mentioning that and a possible source of error.